# copy, paste and echo into txt file mantaining newlines

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I'm doing a  tutorial on the command line. In one of the exercises I'm required to copy-paste a [sonnet](https://www.learnenough.com/command-line-tutorial#fig-copy_paste_sonnet_1) and `echo` it into a new file.
Problem is that the new lines are not present in the new file, in fact, when I `cat` the file, each verse is attached to the previous one.

Do I have to manually add `"\n"` at the end of each line?
I hope there is a better way (because what if there are 1000 lines?)

**UPDATE:**
This is what I have done till now

First I copy the sonnet from [here](https://www.learnenough.com/command-line-tutorial#fig-copy_paste_sonnet_1). Then I  paste it in the terminal to write this command:

```
~$ echo "FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe, That thereby beauties Roſe might neuer die, But as the riper ſhould by time deceaſe, His tender heire might beare his memory: But thou contracted to thine owne bright eyes, Feed’ſt thy lights flame with ſelfe ſubſtantiall fewell, Making a famine where aboundance lies, Thy ſelfe thy foe,to thy ſweet ſelfe too cruell: Thou that art now the worlds freſh ornament, And only herauld to the gaudy ſpring, Within thine owne bud burieſt thy content, And tender chorle makſt waſt in niggarding:    Pitty the world,or elſe this glutton be,    To eate the worlds due,by the graue and thee." > sonnet.txt
```

finally I check the content:

```
cat sonnet.txt
```

but I get:

```
FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe, That thereby beauties Roſe might neuer die, But as the riper ſhould by time deceaſe, His tender heire might beare his memory: But thou contracted to thine owne bright eyes, Feed’ſt thy lights flame with ſelfe ſubſtantiall fewell, Making a famine where aboundance lies, Thy ſelfe thy foe,to thy ſweet ſelfe too cruell: Thou that art now the worlds freſh ornament, And only herauld to the gaudy ſpring, Within thine owne bud burieſt thy content, And tender chorle makſt waſt in niggarding:    Pitty the world,or elſe this glutton be,    To eate the worlds due,by the graue and thee.
```

Comment: Didn't get _copy-paste a sonnet_. Is _sonnet_ is a character file or something else ?

Comment: What command are you using to do this? `echo [paste] > file`? Does the pasted contents have blank lines between each verse?

Comment: @Mahendra, I'm sorry, I forgot to put a link

Answer (score 0):

this will work for sonnets :)

```
$ sonnet="Shall I compare thee to a summer.s day?
> Thou art more lovely and more temperate.
> Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,"

$ echo "$sonnet"
Shall I compare thee to a summer.s day?
Thou art more lovely and more temperate.
Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
```

I think you are missing the double quotes.

```
$ echo $sonnet
Shall I compare thee to a summer.s day? Thou art more lovely and more temperate. Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
```

Comment: It's not working. Please look at the link (I forgot to put before). Try copying and pasting it and then echo it into a txt file. How do you keep the newlines?

Comment: doesn't matter which sonnet/text you use.  Did you pay attention to the quotes?  Both when defining the variable and when echoing back.  Please post exact commands you use in the original post.  Perhaps you're doing something else...

Comment: 1. highlight the sonnet in the page, 2. ctrl-c, 3. type in the terminal "echo", 4. type "$[paste]", 5. type "> sonnet.txt", 6. click enter

Comment: are you typing double quotes to wrap the text you're pasting in step 4?  Can you copy/paste your commands to the original post (not here in the comments) as I did in the answer?

Comment: it looks like your copy/paste doesn't preserve line breaks.  When you paste to a notepad do you see the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107833/discussion-between-pigna-and-karakfa).